# Extending a base class using doctrine, were my base class has 1:n associations

Tags: inheritance, orm, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to work out exactly how to implement a proper separation between two bundles in Symfony and I've run into a doctrine problem.

I have two bundles, a more general bundle (full of abstract classes) called 'BaseProduct' and then an implementation of that bundle (which offers the chance to specialise the functionality of that bundle) called 'ClientProduct'.

I have an two entities within the 'Product' bundle that are associated.

```
abstract class Product 
{
    // One product has many attributes
    private $attributes;

    private function getAttributes()
    {
        return $this->attributes;
    }
}

abstract class Attribute
{
    private $name;
    private $value;

    private function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    private function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

And then a concrete implementation

```
class Product extends BaseProduct/Product
{

}

class Attribute extends BaseProduct/Attribute
{

}
```

*My Question*

First up, I would have used 'mappedSuperclass' to do this, but from reading the docs you cant set up collections as associations (understandably) on non concrete classes.

I'm trying to find another way to do this.

Is this even possible? Because my 'base class' has the relationship to another 'base class' (both abstract). In that case do I need to move the relationship into the 'concrete' implementation or can I keep them at this level (abstract)? My entity definitions ('.yml') are not shown, but I intend to link these to the concrete implementations (where the associations between entities are also between other concrete implementations) and leave the base classes without entity definitions.

Any input welcome - the goal here is to create a decoupled bundle that can be specialised. I'm sure this is a pretty common goal, so I'd be interested to see how others are doing it (if there are any bundles on github doing this I'd be interested to see them).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar, and the work-around I used was to provide a concrete base class which is simply treated as if it were abstract (ie: the base class is never instantiated anywhere).

If you wanted to enforce the "abstractness" of your base class (so other developers don't foolishly try to instantiate one), you can throw an exception in its constructor.

Comment: The problem I've come up against using this approach is that if I create the concrete base class, and then I try to do update my database schema using the console (doctrine:schema:update --force), it complains that the entity metadata mapping file is missing (of course it is, because I don't want the system to treat that entity as being a domain object in my system). This may be unique to symfony, but my workaround is just to comment out the extensions of those files when updating my schema (very annoying). I get the feeling I'm missing something.